# How to run leiningen tests having > (greater than) symbol in their name under Windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, clojure, leiningen, powershell-4.0

I can't refer to tests having `->` in its names because `>` symbol is treated as stdout redirection.

Under PowerShell 4.0 I run current stable Leiningen 2.4.2 with parameters being escaped by `--%`:

```
PS> lein test :only --% my-project.core/foo->bar
```

I see only stderr in the console, but as a side-effect I get `bar` file created with the following content:

```
lein test user

Ran 0 tests containing 0 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
```

Comment: Can I assume you tried passing the namespace as a string: "my-project.core/foo->bar"

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt Yes, I did. I've also tried to escape `>` with `. Unfortunately the result is the same.

Comment: Have you tried single quotes instead of double quotes?

Comment: Try escaping the `>` with `^`, `"my-project.core/foo-^>bar"`. Lein is started via a .bat file from Windows?

Comment: @Entbark Yes, I've also tried single quotes.

Comment: @A.Webb Unfortunately `^` also didn't help. Yes, lein is started via a .bat file.

Comment: The problem seems to be in lein.bat. All escapes go away when `%*` gets expanded in the `:RUN` section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `lein.bat` file. When `%*` gets expanded to all arguments passed on line 303, all my escapes are gone. As a temporary solution I see quoting special symbols with a circumflex (`^`) and then quoting all the circumflexes, which is equal to using `^^^` to make it work:

```
PS> lein test :only my-project.core/foo-^^^>bar
```

Looks ugly, but it works. If there's a better solution, I'd prefer that one.